# Parse a local string date using TimeZoneInfo

Tags: c#, datetimeoffset

I have a string containing a date in Chile: "2018-04-23"

In my country, as I write this post, the timezone offset is -4 hrs.
But going back to that date (April 23), the timezoneoffset was -3 hrs.

The relevant `TimeZoneInfo` containing these arbitrary offset changes is the following:

```
 var tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific SA Standard Time");
```

My goal is to save this date (2018-04-23) in a SQL Server, in a column of type `DateTimeOffset`

So, that date should be saved as: "2018-04-23 00:00:00.000 -03:00" (by visual inspecion using Management Studio)

How can I achieve this programatically?

I tried the following:

```
 var date = DateTime.Parse("2018-04-23");
 var tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific SA Standard Time");

 var utcDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(date, tzi);
 var offset = tzi.GetUtcOffset(utcDate);

 return ((DateTimeOffset)utcDate).ToOffset(offset);
```

But...

- It is not working (it is saved as "2018-04-23 00:00:00.000 -04:00")
- It is too messy

**Another way of asking the same thing is the following:**

I have a local date in no-standard format: "2018-04-23"
The relevant timezoneid for that location is: "Pacific SA Standard Time"
I want the same date in ISO-standard format: "2018-04-23 00:00:00.000 -03:00"

How can I achieve that?
**Inputs:** "2018-04-23" and "Pacific SA Standard Time"
**Output:** "2018-04-23 00:00:00.000 -03:00"

Comment: The problem is, in your 2nd line of code when you create `tzi`, you create a `TimeZoneInfo` object based on today's offset. And I believe there's no `.NET` method to create one based on a past date. You might want to rethink how you store your data.

Comment: You are incorrect regarding tzi. Tzi contains all the different offsets in time. Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/OJsXRr

Comment: -04:00 is correct for Chile.  It is not obvious why you liked -03:00, but beware that Chile had an unusually early daylight savings transition this year.  Happened on April 7th, used to be around the middle of May.

Comment: The chilean date "2018-04-23" in standard iso format is "2018-04-23 00:00:00.00 -03:00". The offset at that moment was -03:00.